Supabase Keycloak Oauth Error: Invalid flow state, no valid flow state foun
First off i have extensively googled and checked the discussion board for an answer. Tried everything i saw but nothing worked. So here i am.
First the setup.
I am running everything locally. I am using keycloak docker and a self hosted version of supabase.
the keycloak client settings are:
Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000/auth/callback; http://localhost:8000/auth/v1/callback
Web Origins: http://localhost:3000; http://localhost:8000
Client Authentication: true

Supabase docker-compose.yml
 GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_ENABLED: "true"
      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID: "supabase"
      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_SECRET: "0L3PRTgpQNx4hnkdamvjQYg8PiZqbS5x"
      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_URL: "http://localhost:8080/realms/master"
      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"

Supabase docker-compose env
ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS="http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"

I am using the Nextjs Supabase template.
I added the following to the actions file.
export const signInwithKeycloak = async () => {
  const supabase = createClient();

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "keycloak",
    options: {
      scopes: "openid",
      redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback",
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error("OAuth error:", error.message);
    return encodedRedirect("error", "/sign-in", error.message);
  }

  console.log("OAuth response data from actions:", data); // Log the response data to ensure you’re receiving the correct URL

  return redirect(data.url); // Ensure this redirects correctly
};

In auth/callback/route.ts
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url);
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get("code");
  const origin = requestUrl.origin;
  const redirectTo = requestUrl.searchParams.get("redirect_to")?.toString();

  const supabase = createClient();

  if (code) {
    console.log("Authorization code found in URL:", code);
    // Attempt to exchange the auth code for a session
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
    console.log("data from callback", data);
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error exchanging code for session:", error.message);
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        `${origin}/sign-in?error=${encodeURIComponent(error.message)}`
      );
    }
  } else {
    console.error("No authorization code found in URL.");
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      `${origin}/sign-in?error=Missing authorization code`
    );
  }

  if (redirectTo) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${redirectTo}`);
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/protected`);
}

On the sign in page i just added a button and set the appropriate formAction.
When i hit Sign in then the "sign in with keycloak" button, i get redirected to the keycloak sign in page. When i login successfully i am redirected to the sign in page for the app with the error "invalid flow state, no valid flow state found".
When i check the cookies i see "sb-localhost-auth-token-code-verifier"
When inspecting network activity:
Request URL: 
http://localhost:8000/auth/v1/authorize?provider=keycloak&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&scopes=openid&code_challenge=Ayzoh0qqlZK9q_BPQRZ4-ao28xkH4C7tvtpuOI3ptFU&code_challenge_method=s256

Payload
provider: keycloak
redirect_to: http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
scopes: openid
code_challenge: Ayzoh0qqlZK9q_BPQRZ4-ao28xkH4C7tvtpuOI3ptFU
code_challenge_method: s256

http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=supabase&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+openid&state=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MjgxMDQxODcsInNpdGVfdXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiaWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJmdW5jdGlvbl9ob29rcyI6bnVsbCwicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJrZXljbG9hayIsInJlZmVycmVyIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2F1dGgvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJmbG93X3N0YXRlX2lkIjoiMzgyZDFhYTEtMzNmMi00NWM3LWI5NGItMzk3YTg5YTBlMjgxIn0.wy5N_hLNJqvh_YNBDrFeuea92KeOdL_ir0eHWwqYz9I

Payload
client_id: supabase
redirect_to: http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
redirect_uri: http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
response_type: code
scope: profile email openid
state: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MjgxMDQxODcsInNpdGVfdXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiaWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJmdW5jdGlvbl9ob29rcyI6bnVsbCwicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJrZXljbG9hayIsInJlZmVycmVyIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2F1dGgvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJmbG93X3N0YXRlX2lkIjoiMzgyZDFhYTEtMzNmMi00NWM3LWI5NGItMzk3YTg5YTBlMjgxIn0.wy5N_hLNJqvh_YNBDrFeuea92KeOdL_ir0eHWwqYz9I

http://localhost:3000/auth/callback?state=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MjgxMDQxODcsInNpdGVfdXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiaWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJmdW5jdGlvbl9ob29rcyI6bnVsbCwicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJrZXljbG9hayIsInJlZmVycmVyIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2F1dGgvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJmbG93X3N0YXRlX2lkIjoiMzgyZDFhYTEtMzNmMi00NWM3LWI5NGItMzk3YTg5YTBlMjgxIn0.wy5N_hLNJqvh_YNBDrFeuea92KeOdL_ir0eHWwqYz9I&session_state=181a8fe2-2bf5-4279-8bfd-c8880d89c51c&iss=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Frealms%2Fmaster&code=03399bd7-f454-4e89-bd7d-e04eec6908d4.181a8fe2-2bf5-4279-8bfd-c8880d89c51c.b37b3d25-c578-4ad6-afa8-03f6a6bbae02

Payload
state: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MjgxMDQxODcsInNpdGVfdXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiaWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJmdW5jdGlvbl9ob29rcyI6bnVsbCwicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJrZXljbG9hayIsInJlZmVycmVyIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2F1dGgvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJmbG93X3N0YXRlX2lkIjoiMzgyZDFhYTEtMzNmMi00NWM3LWI5NGItMzk3YTg5YTBlMjgxIn0.wy5N_hLNJqvh_YNBDrFeuea92KeOdL_ir0eHWwqYz9I
session_state: 181a8fe2-2bf5-4279-8bfd-c8880d89c51c
iss: http://localhost:8080/realms/master
code: 03399bd7-f454-4e89-bd7d-e04eec6908d4.181a8fe2-2bf5-4279-8bfd-c8880d89c51c.b37b3d25-c578-4ad6-afa8-03f6a6bbae02

If you require any other info please let me know. I tried to keep as many defaults as possible.

You need to use HTTPS with openID connect, otherwise some of the key cookies will be blocked by the browser. (due to the samesite cookie protection). I wrote a blog post about troubleshooting cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

OK I will try to setup up the local instances to use https
